# Spring Batch - Step on FAILED was not invoked

Tags: spring-batch

my Spring Batch configuration is posted below.
The problem is that I don't understand why step rename-file-step was not invoked.

My test scenario:

1. Step copy-file-step is completed.
2. During invocation of ItemWriter in step copy-file-step a rollback exception occurs.

The ExitStatus of my-import-step is FAILED. 
I expect that rename-file-step should be invoked but it is not.
Could anyone help in explanation? Thanks in advance!

More details:
In Job Repository(DB), for the step my-import-step:
exitCode: FAILED, status: UNKNOWN.

```html
     <batch:job id="myImportJob">  
        <batch:step id="copy-file-step" next="my-import-step">  
            <batch:tasklet ref="sftpRequestTasklet"/>  
        </batch:step>  
        <batch:step id="my-import-step">    
            <batch:tasklet>  
                <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader"  
                             writer="myItemWriter"
                             commit-interval="10000">
                </batch:chunk>  
                <batch:transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT" propagation="REQUIRED"/>  
                </batch:tasklet>  
                <batch:next on="*" to="delete-file-step" />  
                <batch:next on="FAILED" to="rename-file-step" />  
            </batch:step>  
            <batch:step id="delete-file-step">  
                <batch:tasklet ref="deleteFileTasklet" />  
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step id="rename-file-step">
                <batch:tasklet ref="renameFileTasklet" />
            </batch:step>  
        </batch:job>
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for that not to work (I have a test that does the same thing and it passes).  What version are you using?

Comment: spring-batch-core 3.0.1

Comment: What are the statuses in the job repository?

Comment: Status: Failed, Exit_Code: Failed, so as expected but logs are telling something different.

Comment: What happens if you pull out the transaction-attributes piece?

Comment: After removing the transaction-attributes nothing has changed.

Comment: Ah…I just realized that the status in your repository is UNKNOWN.  The UNKNOWN status comes from when the job repository can't be updated for some reason.  Have you turned debug logging on?  Why is that step failing in the first place?  If this is a test scenario, are you sure it's failing for the reason you expect?

Comment: yes I have debug loggin on. This step is failing because of the RollbackException. This is as I expect. But in DB the exitCode is FAILED so it should invoke this <batch:next on="FAILED" to="rename-file-step" />

Comment: If the BatchStatus is UNKNOWN, it doesn't matter what the `ExitStatus` is, the job terminates because the framework isn't clear on the current state of things.

Comment: OK. Thanks for explanation. I've isolated the problem. When I just throw any runtime exception in my Writer the on FAILED is correctly executed. In my Writer I call a service method which  throws RollbackException. That causes than BatchStatus UNKNOWN. Probably I made a mistake in configuration. I use Spring Admin with one transaction manager for job repository. And the service method uses other transaction manager from application. I'm not sure and I'm still searching for the exact problem but for sure there is a problem in transactions.